# Problema con clase JAVA

Tags: java, apache, eclipse

El problema es el siguiente,
Estaba modificando una clase java, y por alguna causa tuve que reiniciar mi computadora y al momento de volver abrir mi clase java, mi código desaparecio y me muestra lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien puede decirme que paso y como resolverlo ya que me urge el código que tenia en esa clase :s

Comment: ¿Has intentado abrirlo con otros editores? O tal vez verificar si se cambio la codificación.

Comment: Si lo abri con el Notepad++ y me marca puros NULL NULL NULL NULL y si cambio la codificación se muestra como texto vacio :S

Comment: Pues es muy raro lo que te paso, pero podria decirse que tu codigo se daño, no se si se reinicio de golpe tu maquina. Ojala puedas recupera tu archivo.

Comment: ¡Qué pena! Si no tienes copia de seguridad o una copia del tipo Time Machine quizá tengas que escribir de nuevo tu clase :( bueno, a todos nos han pasado cosas parecidas. Pon remedio: a) Yo desde hace tiempo tengo mis proyectos sincronizados con Github, existen herramientas para ello: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/egit-tutorial/  b) También, como medida de seguridad, sincronizo mi carpeta de proyectos con una cuenta de Dropbox o Google Drive, así, si pasa algo tengo copia del código en dos sitios. Revisa toda tu carpeta de proyectos, quien sabe si hay por ahí una copia del archivo.

Comment: He solucionado el problema, por suerte tenia el .CLASS, y mediante un decompilador online http://www.javadecompilers.com/ pude recuperar el código no hasta donde lo tenia pero ya me evito de escribir todo. Gracias por las sugerencias.

Comment: Me alegro. Que el susto sirva para implementar una estrategia de copias de seguridad. Saludos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He solucionado el problema, por suerte tenia el .CLASS, y mediante un decompilador online javadecompilers.com pude recuperar el código no hasta donde lo tenia pero ya me evito de escribir todo. Gracias por las sugerencias.